# controller concerns in rails 4, sharing actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, activesupport-concern

i am trying to share an action between controllers using a concern like for example:

```
module Backend
  module Exportable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def show
      respond_to do |format|
        format.xls { set_excel_headers "#{controller_name.classify}_#{params[:id]}_#{Time.now.to_i.to_s}.xls" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Do you see any problems with this?

Should I never shared default actions from rails through concerns?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a file in **concerns** directory (named same as your module : ***backend.rb***)

and here is your code :

```
module Backend
    def show
        respond_to do |format|
            format.xls { set_excel_headers "#{controller_name.classify}_#{params[:id]}_#{Time.now.to_i.to_s}.xls" }
        end
    end
end
```

So in your controller you add :

```
extend Backend
```

Comment: sorry my question is not how I do this. this code is working, backend is an engine. I am asking is if it makes sense to define such a thing. A concern with default actions inside like show, or index or w/e!

Comment: i'm sorry for misunderstanding your question .. but now we are ok.
i think what you are using can make sense if the "show" action is the same in all controllers.
I mean you can do that to apply the DRY principle